# How to add slicer by Column in Power BI

Tags: powerbi

I am new to [Power BI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eC8jA.png). I have some specific requirement which I would like to explain to you.

I have these columns:

- FY17 Sales
- FY17 Gross Margin
- FY18 BUDGET Sales
- FY18 BUDGET Gross Margin
- FY18 Forecast Sales
- FY18 Forecast Gross Margin

What my requirement is:

1. I want to add slicer for sales and Gross Margin. So if I select
   `Sales` I will have sales of all the year `FY17 Sales`, `FY18 Budget
   Sales` and `FY18 Forecast Sales` and same goes with gross Margin
2. And I want to add other slicer for `FY17`, `FY18 Budget` and `FY18
   Forecast`, so for example of I select `FY17` i will get the data of
   `FY17 Sales`, `FY17 Gross Margin` and same with `FY18 Budget` and `FY18
   Forecast`.

I hope you will gonna help me out here, this is really crucial for me.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Look in to book-marks.

You'll create a 'bookmark' (read: view) for each way you want to see the page by hiding/changing your visuals.

Then add a button for each view that you want and link your bookmarks to the buttons as actions.